# How to obtain additional data from select options choice in React / Typescript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, select-options

I have an array of exchanges, once the user selects an exchange, I want to use both the exchange's name and its base quote.

For example, if the user selects the first option below, I want to capture `"poloniex"` as well as the base key `"USDC"`.

[image]

First I tried using this:

```
{exchanges.map((exchange, i) =>
  (<option key={i} value={exchange.exchange} base={exchange.quote}>
    {capFirst(exchange.exchange)} ({exchange.quote}) ${exchange.price_quote}
  </option>))}
```

However I get the error that `base` does not exist, however shouldn't I be able to add any attribute to an option? Perhaps not if it's in JSX? Also `data` didn't work.

> Type '{ children: string[]; key: number; value: string; base: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLOptionElement>'.
>     Property 'base' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLOptionElement>'.ts(2322)

Another way I tried is to get the index key of the option selected, however the follow code produces `key = null`.

Below `target.value` will give me its value, but I also need the base quote.

```
@bind
handleExchangeSelect(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
  const { exchanges } = this.props;
  const target = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
  console.log('target', target);
  const exchange = target.value;
  const key = target.getAttribute('key');
  console.log('exchange', exchange);
  console.log('key', key);
  // if (key) {
  //   console.log(exchanges[Number(key)]);
  // }
  this.setState({
    exchange,
    // exchange_base: base ? base : ''
  });
}
```

Comment: With react there is no need to encode data into the DOM (with very few exceptions). Also adding arbitrary attributes to DOM elements violates the HTML standard. `base` is not a valid attribute on an `<option>` element. Components can hold all the required data internally.

Comment: @trixn could you post your example? I found a way to accomplish this, but seems like there should be a better more straight forward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react way to solve that would be to create an own select component which could look like this:

```
class ExchangeSelect extends Component {
    handleSelect = event => {
        const {exchanges, onSelect} = this.props;
        const selected = exchanges.find(exchange => exchange.exchange === event.target.value);
        onSelect(selected);
    };

    render() {
        const {exchanges} = this.props;

        return (
            <select onChange={this.handleSelect}>
                {exchanges.map(exchange => (
                    <option key={exchange.exchange} value={exchange.exchange}>
                        {exchange.exchange} ({exchange.quote}) ${exchange.price_quote}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

With `exchanges` being a list of exchange objects you could then use it like this:

```
const exchanges = [
    {exchange: 'poloniex', quote: 'USDC', price_quote: '0.42'},
    {exchange: 'bitibu', quote: 'USDT', price_quote: '0.666'},
    {exchange: 'bittrex', quote: 'USDT', price_quote: '0.21'},
];
```

In render():

```
<ExchangeSelect 
    exchanges={exchanges} 
    onSelect={exchange => console.log(exchange.quote)} 
/>
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit 2z23n1n26n]

Answer (score 2):

I'm hoping for a more obvious, cleaner way, but I found this and it works:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

> **Note**
>
> You can pass an array into the value attribute, allowing you to select multiple options in a select tag:

`<select multiple={true} value={['B', 'C']}>`

### Solution in my app

**The select options**

```
{exchanges.map((exchange, i) =>
  (<option key={i} value={[exchange.exchange, exchange.quote]}>
    {capFirst(exchange.exchange)} ({exchange.quote}) ${exchange.price_quote}
  </option>))}
```

**The select handler**

```
@bind
handleExchangeSelect(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
  const exchangeValues = target.value.split(',');
  const exchange = exchangeValues[0];
  const exchange_base = exchangeValues[1];
  console.log('exchange', exchange);
  console.log('exchange_base', exchange_base);
  this.setState({
    exchange,
    exchange_base
  });
}
```

**This gets me what I wanted:**

```
{ 
  exchange: 'gdax',
  exchange_base: 'USD'
}
```